# launch icons not displaying in emulator or on a device

Tags: android, icons, mipmaps

The launch icons are not showing on either the emulator or a device when I run the App. There is a similar questions but the answer provided does not resolve this for me so I think it warrants posing the question again.

I have added the required tags in the manifest file. The ic_launcher clipart icons were generated using the Configure Image Asset facility with the default name of ic_launcher and they are there in the mipmaps folder under the headings:

```
 ic_launcher(6)
 ic_launcher_foreground(5)
 ic_launcher_round(6)
```

The Manifest file is as follows:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_descriptor">
    <activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://www.example.com/gizmos” -->
            <data android:scheme="http"
                android:host="https://wwww.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/kalkan"/>
            <!-- note that the leading "/" is required for pathPrefix-->
            <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "example://gizmos” -->
            <data android:scheme="rental"
                android:host="kalkan" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".DetailActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".MapsActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".ListActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".AboutKalkanActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".WebActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".OwnerImageUploadActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".OwnerInputDataActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".OwnerLoginActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".OwnerMainActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".OwnerMapActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".OwnerResetPasswordActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".OwnerSignupActivity" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />

</application>
```

Comment: if you ctrl+click the image name in the manifest, does it open the image file?

Comment: When you say the launcher icon is not shown, do you still see the default Android launcher icons?

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley image name in the Manifest??  There is no image name in the Manifest as you can see

Comment: @AnkyAn no icons at all are showing.

Comment: @PhilipS android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley Hi. Ctrl+click give a drop down menu and does not open the image files

Comment: @PhilipS I'll help you troubleshoot the issue. When you see the dropdown menu of the icons, click one of them, does it show the icon you expected? Under mipmap/ic_launcher, can you preview the images? The new adaptive and legacy icons are composed of both foreground and background images. I'm not sure why you don't have the background images. Can you double check?

Comment: @AnkyAn Hi, many thanks. I think I can see what the problem is but not how to resolve it. At one point I refactored the App name and now I think  it may not be finding the relevant files.

If I Ctrl + click one of the ic_launcher.png and run Analyse/Inspect Code it returns errors.

Error:(6, 33) cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'vector'.
Error:(1, 56) s4s-elt-schema-ns: The namespace of element 'x' must be from the schema namespace,'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'.

Comment: @AnkyAn Error:(1, 56) s4s-elt-invalid: Element 'x' is not a valid element in a schema document.
Error:(1, 56) schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'null', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.

Comment: @PhilipS I think your files are corrupted. There are 2 things you can do. 1. Save a copy of your current project. Delete ic_launcher and ic_launcher_round. Go to File->New->Image Assets, and create default legacy launcher icons. Run the project. If you can see the icons now, create the launcher icons you want again. 2. If you user version control, go back to the commit when the launcher icon is fine. Compare that commit wiht your current code.

Comment: @AnkyAn Hi. I tried deleting and creating the launcher icons but to no avail. I don't like being defeated and would have liked to resolve this, but have gone back to an earlier version. Many thanks for your help and suggestions